Having an Issue with my JComboBox filling the entire JFrame/ Not displaying options
I am working on my final project for class and need some input on why my JComboBox isn't working properly. When I had it in the main program "GUI" I was able to display it properly but I couldn't get it to return the option that was selected. Now after moving it to its own class "OptionChoices" when I create the object and add it to the JFrame it takes up the entire window. Essentially my hope for the program is that it will provide the combo box with choices, take the input and then display certain information based on the choice selected. I am pretty new to GUI and can't figure out whats going on with it. Any help would be appreciated.
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class GUI {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mood Food");
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(700, 800);
            frame.setLocation(430, 100);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 

            frame.add(panel);
            var name = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");

            JLabel lblName = new JLabel(name + " ,welcome to the Mood Food Program");
            lblName.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            panel.add(lblName);

            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("How are you feeling today?");
            lbl.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            panel.add(lbl);

            JComboBox<String> jBox = new OptionChoices();
            panel.add(jBox);



            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setVisible(false);
            frame.add(panel2);

            JLabel newText = new JLabel();
            panel2.add(newText);

            JButton btn = new JButton("OK");
            btn.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT); // added code
            panel.add(btn);
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    boolean visible = panel.isVisible();
                    panel.setVisible(!visible);
                    panel2.setVisible(visible);
                    }});

            frame.setVisible(true); // added code

        }
    }

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class OptionChoices extends JComboBox {
        public String comboOptions() {
            String[] choices = {"Select..", "Happy", "Content", "Grateful", "Sad",
                    "Angry", "Lonely", "Heartbroken", "Worried", "Anxious",     "Jealous"};

            JComboBox<String> emotions = new JComboBox<String>(choices);
            emotions.setMaximumSize(getPreferredSize());
            emotions.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

            String emotionText = String.valueOf(emotions.getSelectedItem());

            return emotionText;
        }
    }

